# Remove whitespaces in between strings in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, removing-whitespace

I want to remove whitespaces from a word like this:

```
str1 = "101 - purple cloths"

str1sp = removespace(srt1)

print(str1sp) 

>>>>> 101-purple cloths
```

The result should onlt take out whitespaces round the hyphen (-). This would be done for an entire column.

Comment: `df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace('\s-\s', '-')`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `\s*-\s*` as pattern:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'\s*-\s*', '-', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
                   col                new
0  101 - purple cloths  101-purple cloths
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bzuf6T/1)